# Get seperate two values and add together in every hour when the code is running using python

Tags: python, date, time

Here I have two values 40 and 50 in the csv file. Then I want to decrement the value in every hour separately and this will continuously running the code up to 24 hours.
So what I need to do is , I want to read that two changing values in every hour and do summation and read it as one output. I need this happened in every hour up to 24 hours.

So here I wrote the code for to read that two values and decrement in every one hour upto 24 hours.
***50 will decrement in every hour 2.567
40 will decrement in every hour 1.234***

Here is the code for the decrement process of two values. But unfortunately I have no idea how I can add that two values from taking that running code and read it as one input .

Can anyone help me to solve this process?

```
     x = data[data['a'] == 50]
     x now = x.iloc[0].loc['a']
     last_x_value = 0
     current_time = x.iloc[0].loc['date']
     x_decrement_constant = math.exp((-2.567 * 1))
     required_hours_of_generated_data = 24          # Generate data for this many hours.
     X' = [{'date':current_time, 'a':x now }]
     while True: 
   next_record_time = current_time + timedelta(0,3600)
       if(last_x_value < len(x)-1):

    if(next_record_time < x.iloc[last_x_value + 1].loc['date']):
        new_x = (x_now* x_decrement_constant)

    else:
        new_x = (x_now* x_decrement_constant) + x.iloc[last_x_value + 1].loc['a']
        last_x_value = last_x_value + 1

        else:
        break


              y = data[data['b'] == 40]
              y now = x.iloc[0].loc['b']
              last_y_value = 0
              current_time = x.iloc[0].loc['date']
              x_decrement_constant = math.exp((-1.234* 1))
              required_hours_of_generated_data = 24             # Generate data for this many hours.
              Y' = [{'date':current_time, 'b':y now }]
           while True: 
          next_record_time = current_time + timedelta(0,3600)
              if(last_y_value < len(y)-1):

       if(next_record_time < y.iloc[last_y_value + 1].loc['date']):
        new_y = (y_now* y_decrement_constant)

        else:
        new_y = (y_now* y_decrement_constant) + y.iloc[last_y_value + 1].loc['b']
        last_y_value = last_y_value + 1

        else:
        break
```

Comment: Can you limit the question to one thing? Do you need help reading a csv file, or using time.sleep, or ... going by your comment you need help adding two numbers? That can't be right. :)

Comment: Actually I need to read that changing two values in every hour as a one output (summation)  By using this code. Can't we do this? Can you suggest me some options?